# What kind of exercise is bouldering?

Tags: health, bouldering

Is it more cardiovascular or weight training? If I want to add an additional exercise on non bouldering days, what would be most beneficial to my overall health and life longevity?

Comment: I think this is far too vague to have a meaningful answer.

Comment: What is bouldering?

Comment: @BriHan Bouldering is a form of rock climbing in which very short but difficult routes are climbed, sufficiently close to the ground that foam mats, rather than ropes, can be used for fall protection.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is overall health and longevity, the World Health Organisation recommends<sup>[1](https://www.who.int/news-room/fact-sheets/detail/physical-activity)</sup> that adults should do at least 150–300 minutes of moderate-intensity aerobic physical activity per week, or at least half that amount of vigorous-intensity aerobic physical activity, plus muscle-strengthening activities that involve all major muscle groups on 2 or more days a week.

Bouldering does not particularly fulfil either of those recommendations, as it isn't aerobic exercise, and really only strengthens the gripping, pulling, and core muscles of the upper body. That's certainly not to say it's a waste of time - as it's still physical activity, and certainly provides physical, social, and mental benefits. But if your goal is overall health and longevity, the best additional forms of exercise to take on would be whatever you are lacking from the WHO recommendations. So if you're doing strength training once per week in addition to your bouldering, but never doing any cardio, you highest priority should probably be to add some cardio. Or if you're already doing cardio, consider adding some lower body strength training and upper body pushing training.